# How can I use AVFoundation or AVAsset to create a Subtitle on top of my video?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, avfoundation

I have a customized Player using compositions and some AVAssets. Everything works fine. Now I would like to to some Subtitle on top of my video. I've read in the documentation, that a mediaType "AVMediaTypeSubtitle" exists. Is there any Asset or AVAssetTrack, which can generate a TextOverlay, which I could insert into my composition to do subtitles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a better solution then mine, but you can use text overlay using CATextLayer in AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.